# Replacing existing panel group layout with new on the click of command link from MAF

Tags: oracle-maf

I am working on maf project. I have amx page with 3 panel group layouts. On the click of command link I want to replace the existing panel group layout with another on the same amx page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rendered` or `styleClass` (or `inlineStyle`) in combination with an EL to hide/show an `amx:panelGroupLayout`. 
Or use JavaScript (like jQuery with `toggle()` or `show()`/`hide()`).

Answer (score -1):

You can bind the `rendered` property to a boolean variable in your bean Class. Then on your `actionEvent` of your button click you can set true/false value to the variable. 
Then based on your requirement you can replace the `amx:panelGroupLayout` with another `amx:panelGroupLayout`